# How do I create a Logger using Decorator pattern for method injection in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I want to create a logger as a decorator on ILogger. That is, I want classes to get MY logger injected when requesting ILogger from ioc. My logger will be depending on ILogger otherwise set up in ioc, or at least I'd like my logger to receive a configured ILogger in constructor.

The ILogger will be consumed in an Azure Function through method injection, if that makes a difference.

I have serviceCollection.AddLogging() and "just need to add" my Decorator. How do I do that?

```
public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
  public MyLogger(ILogger internal)
  {
  }
}

public class AftOrchestration
{
    [FunctionName("Process")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
        HttpRequest httpRequest,
        ILogger logger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: As well as implementing an `ILogger` you also need to create an implementation of `ILoggerProvider`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider#custom-logger-provider